# How to make this function into a loop?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

```
let trafficFirstLightColor = 'black';
let trafficSecondLightColor = 'black';
let trafficThirdLightColor = 'black';
let start;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  trafficFirstLightColor = 'black';
  trafficSecondLightColor = 'black';
  trafficThirdLightColor = 'black';
  start = millis();
}

function draw() {
  fill(trafficFirstLightColor);
  ellipse(315, 40, 20, 20);
  fill(trafficSecondLightColor);
  ellipse(315, 40 + 25 * 1, 20, 20);
  fill(trafficThirdLightColor);
  ellipse(315, 40 + 25 * 2, 20, 20);
  
  const now = millis();
  const cycle = now - start;
  
  if (cycle < 3000) {
    if (trafficFirstLightColor === 'black' &&
    trafficSecondLightColor === 'black' &&
    trafficThirdLightColor === 'black') {
      trafficFirstLightColor = 'red';
      return;
    }
  } else if (cycle < 6000) {
    if (trafficFirstLightColor === 'red') {
      trafficFirstLightColor = 'black';
      trafficSecondLightColor = 'yellow';
      return;
    }
  } else if (cycle < 9000) {
    if (trafficSecondLightColor === 'yellow') {
      trafficSecondLightColor = 'black';
      trafficThirdLightColor = 'green';
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

I made a traffic light and get help from this community; however, it is not a loop…

So basic function is, if it touches the black, let first traffic light be red, and continued.

The only problem is when the code finished, it just finished. Can we making it into a loop?

Comment: Wasn't this [already asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76134158/6243352)? If you didn't understand or weren't satisfied with my answer, you could have commented to ask for clarification.

Comment: Yes, but I wanna to make it into a loop....

Answer (score 1):

By using async/await you can write a function that 'sleeps' for a number of seconds, we can then use that function instead of calling setTimeout and setInterval.

(Unfortunately there is no built in sleep function in JavaScript, but we can create one with a oneliner, basically we create a promise that will resolve after a number of ms that you choose when you call the sleep function. And since await is just one way of calling promises **await sleep(milliseconds)** then works fine inside an async function.)

We create an array with the sequence and  time each light should be on, easy to find and change since it is separate from the rest of the programming logic.

Then we just loop through that array inside an endless while loop, turn the right light on, sleep for the duration specified in the array and turn the light off, moving on to the next part of the sequence in the next iteration of the loop, and so on...

You can adopt this to your approach for the output using canvas and keep the same basic logic, 'sleeping' between different stages in the sequence - inside a loop.

```js
async function trafficLight() {
  // a function that let us sleep/pause for a number of ms
  const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
  // get the div for each light
  const [red, yellow, green] =
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.traffic-light div')];
  // how many seconds should each light be on in a sequence
  const onForSeconds = [
    [red, 5],
    [yellow, 1],
    [green, 4],
    [yellow, 1]
  ];
  // run the sequence forever
  while(true){
    for (let [light, seconds] of onForSeconds) {
     light.classList.add('active');
     await sleep(seconds * 1000);
     light.classList.remove('active');
    }
  }
}

trafficLight();
```

```css
.traffic-light {
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
}

.traffic-light div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

.red.active {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.green.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Traffic-lights</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="traffic-light">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="yellow"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: using recursion is not a great idea. After a while you will reach the maximum recursion depth. Even if for this particular case it will take forever to reach a recursion limit in general this is not a robust solution.

Comment: Changed the answer to an endless while loop - instead of recursion. (Although the recursion would probalby take days to reach call stack maximum - we can't have that - we want an endless traffic light...)